# Calculating Standard Deviation of the Volume of a Cube

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

Let's say  I have a machine that makes cubes. My goal is to determine the average and standard deviation the volume of a cube.

I have N length, width and height measurements. I do not believe these variables are independent (since they are all coming from the same machine).

The product of the average length, width and height would give me the average volume, but how would I determine the standard deviation?

Edit: although I have 3 columns of data, they are not arranged such that row 1 is length, width and height from the same cube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dataset with three columns - one for length, one for width, one for height - then I would suggest that you create a fourth column for volume. The volume column should be the product of the length, width, and height columns.

Then you can take the sample average and the sample standard deviation in the way that you generally would: $\bar{x}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{V_i}{N}$ and $s_x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N(V_i-\bar{V})^2}$, where $V_i$ is the volume of the $i$th cube.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I realized this was the obvious answer when I was writing the question. Thanks for confirming that would be a valid approach, but I am also interested in the theory of how I could compare these data sets. So let's say that I do not have 1:1 length, width and height data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, you do not have 1:1 length, width, and height data?

Comment: although I have 3 columns of data, they are not arranged such that row 1 is length, width and height from the same cube.

Comment: You will get a different answer. For example, consider the sample mean: $\bar{x}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{V_i}{N}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{l_i\times w_i\times h_i}{N}$. There is no way to break this sum up in a way to ignore the indices $i$. If you are not able to make sure each length, width, and height is from the same cube, then you may not be able to come up with a good estimator for the sample mean of the volume of the cubes. You could attempt to do the average height times the average width times the average length, but this will get you a different calculation than the one above.

Comment: If you think that the machine creating a cube affects a cube's height and width jointly (i.e. if the machine creates a cube with a larger-than-normal width, then this have an effect on the height of the cube) then it would be especially bad to use a method where a cube's length, width, and height are not properly associated with one another.