# Determine the variabilty of the volume given the length, width and height

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova, variance, experiment-design

I am to solve a problem where I am given the mean value, $\mu_i$ and variance, $\sigma^2_i$ where $i\in{L,W,H}$ which represents the Length, Widht and Height related variables respectively.

The question is as follow: *We have three different variables, length (L), width (W) and height (H) which can be manufactured using different precisions. Find the approximate variance of the volume of the box*

It is stated that we can assume that the variables are independant. I am given the values $\mu_L=12, \mu_W=8,\mu_H=6$ and $\sigma^2_L=0.06, \sigma^2_W=0.05, \sigma^2_H=0.04$

### My solution

Given that we know that the Volume, $V$, can be calculated as $L\cdot H\cdot W$ we can determine that V is a non-linear combination.

Since we have that $V=g(L,W,H)$ where $g$ is a non-linear function I apply the formula:

\begin{equation}
  \mu_V\simeq g(\mu_L,\mu_W,\mu_H)=\mu_L\cdot\mu_W\cdot\mu_H=576
\end{equation}

and that the variance for V, $\sigma^2_V$ can be calculated using:

\begin{equation}
\sigma^2_V \simeq\sum_{i=L}^{n} \biggr(\frac{\delta g}{\delta x_i}\biggr\rvert_{\mu_L,\mu_H,\mu_W}\biggr)^2\sigma^2_i =(\mu_W\cdot\mu_H)^2\sigma^2_L+(\mu_L\cdot\mu_W)^2\sigma^2_H+(\mu_L\cdot\mu_H)\sigma^2_W=766
\end{equation}

### Actual solution

I do *not* know whether my answer is correct or not, because the provided solution states the following explanation (this is the entire solution, there are no comments etc.):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{split}
\overline{c}\pm3\sqrt{\overline{c}}
\\
\overline{c}=\frac{56}{15}=3.73
\\
UCL=3.73\pm3\sqrt{3.73}=9.52
\\
CL=3.73
\\
LCL = 3.73-3\sqrt{3.73}=-2.06
\end{split}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The question consists of 2 parts where I am at the first part. The next part is:

*Which one of the variables L, H, W constitutes most to the variance of the box's volume? Motivate your answer based on your calculations in a)*

I am quite confused as to why the solution looks like it does. It seems to not be answering either question a nor b? Numerically we seem to come to vastly different conclusions so I may have understood the question much different than what is actually asked. I have found the similar looking question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213514/calculating-standard-deviation-of-the-volume-of-a-cube) but that seems to calculate $\mu_L, \mu_W$ etc. where I am already given those.

Comment: Your $\mu_V$ and $\sigma^2_V$ seem correct, and the 2nd term of the variance is largest by far. A simulation in R based on a million volumes and assuming independent normal lengths, widths, and heights gives almost exactly the same values you got, and volumes are very nearly normal. // I assume the 'answer' is a misprint because I can see no connection between it and the problem. (By far, this wouldn't be the first ever answer book error.) Perhaps browsing nearby problems and answers you can find a more likely match between Qs and As.

Comment: @BruceET       Thanks for answering! I was certainly confused as to why the answer calculated UCL and LCL, or where the values 56 and 15 came from. It is a solution of a test exam and I don't have solution in the "regular" book. This was the first question of this type so I thought it was correct in the solution, and that I had misunderstood the chapter profoundly. Merry christmas!

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R simulation mentioned in my Comment:

```
set.seed(2020)
L = rnorm(10^6,12, sqrt(.06))
W = rnorm(10^6,8, sqrt(.05))
H = rnorm(10^6,6, sqrt(.04))
V = L*W*H
summary(V); var(V); sd(V)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  451.9   557.1   575.6   576.0   594.4   727.0 
[1] 766.321
[1] 27.6825
hist(V, prob=T)
 curve(dnorm(x,576,27.7), add=T)
```

[image]